# How do I allow multiple keys to unlock a container block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a container that unlocks for several keys, so far my testing says that only 1 key can be in place at a time. is there a way around this to have multiple keys?

I'm playing Minecraft Java Edition 1.12.2

Comment: does anyone even know?

Comment: is it possible WITHOUT the lock tag?

Comment: i need multiple locks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly! The `Lock` tag only accepts one item name. You could have multiple items with the same name instead.

But what you *could* do is repeatedly test if there is a player near the chest, and if they have an acceptable key, update the chest's `Lock` tag to match the name of the acceptable item.

For example, let's have our keys named `AliceKey` and `BobKey`, given to players Alice and Bob respectively. Summon an invisible armour stand on the chest with the tag `chestKeys`, then create separate command chains for each possible key:

```
Rpt: /execute @e[tag=chestKeys] ~ ~ ~ testfor @p {Inventory:[{tag:{display:{Name:"AliceKey"}}}]}
Cnd: /blockdata 12 23 34 {Lock:"AliceKey"}
```

---

## 1.13+

Command syntax was heavily changed in 1.13, and so the commands above won't work. Instead, use the new versions of `/execute` and `/blockdata`:

```
Rpt: /execute at @e[tag=chestKeys] if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:{tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"AliceKey"}'}}}}] run data merge block 12 23 34 {Lock:"AliceKey"}
```

Comment: the thing is, i need multiple keys is there any way maybe not using the lock tag?

Comment: hm i will test this to see if it works

Comment: is there a way to test it with the player HOLDING the item?

Comment: @anomanous You don't need to. The `Lock` tag has that functionality built in.

Comment: huh, thanks! you make this a whole lot easier!